# Mysql keeps giving error when inserting to database

Tags: mysql, php

I try to add values to MySQL database from a form input and it used to work ok, recently it started giving me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES('כיריים על השיש','1','9')' at line 1.

my code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['cat_name']))
{       
    $cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_name']);
    $parent   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parent']);
    $grp      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['grp']);

    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql          = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE cat_name='$cat_name' LIMIT 1");
    $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

    if ($productMatch > 0) 
    {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Category" into the system, <a href="category_add.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }

    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql2    = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (cat_name,parent,group) VALUES('$cat_name','$parent','$grp')") or die (mysql_error());
    $cid     = mysql_insert_id();
    $newname = "$cid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../cat_images/$newname");
    header("location: category_add.php"); 
    exit();
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3):

use this query, `group` is reserved word in mysql. You have to append `` ` `` with column names.

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (`cat_name`,`parent`,`group`) VALUES('$cat_name','$parent','$grp')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: You asked 6 question. And none accepted. Its good habit to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @user2003332 : once you are satisfy with the answer, accept it.